# Remplazar espacio por guiones en php

Tags: php, input, procesamiento-de-texto, ajustar-texto

Disculpen amigos soy nuevo en php de echo este es el primer codigo php

Busco alguna forma en php de convertir texto con espacios a texto con guiones, por ejemplo
**Este es un texto sin guiones**
pasarlo a
**Este-es-un-texto-con-guiones**

Tengo este html [Texto a guiones](https://uniq.edu.mx/insertar-guiones-en-texto-con-php-o-cambiar-palabra-en-sublime-text/)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Convertir texto a texto con guiones</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<center>
    <form action="tolink.php" method="post">
 <p>Su nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
</center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Es un formulario y lo que deseo hacer es que el codigo 2, tome el texto que se introduce en el codigo 1 y lo procese.

Codigo 2 php

```
<?php
$text = "[Texto introducido en el 1]";

$text = preg_replace_callback("~\[([^\]]*)]~", function($s) {
    return ''.str_replace(" ", "-", $s[1]).' ';
    }, $text);

print $text;
  ?>
```

El codigo 2 solo funciona bien, pero quiero modificarlo para que tome valores del 1, o juntar todo en un solo codigo

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Qué significa *agregarle algun input para que online se introduzca el texto y lo tome $text, despues algun boton para correrlo y arroje el resultado*? Parece ser el núcleo de la pregunta, pero no se entiende. Además, indica lo que hayas investigado/intentado y qué errores/problemas tienes? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias he editado la pregunta a ver si me explico

Comment: El título difiere con la descripción, título: 'Agregarle un input a mi php'. descripción: 'replazar espacios por guiones'

Comment: En la pagina 2 solo tienes que modificar la parte del str_replace y quitar la funcion, deje la respuesta, puedes ver el ejemplo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es en tu pagina1.php tener un buscador y lo que se teclee o busque, te redirija a pagina2.php asegurate de que "tulink.php" sea la pagina2 (donde se mostrará el mensaje), te dejo el mismo codigo que has puesto.

pagina1.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="" action="pagina2.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="Search">
        <button type="submit" name="button">Search</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Despues este es en la pagina2 donde se mostrara el mensaje, aqui puedes poner solo tu codigo php, pero para mantener la estructura deje el html:

pagina2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['search'])){
          
            $text = $_POST['search'];
         //Aqui convertiras el text y agregaras los guiones
         $cadenaConvert = str_replace(" ", "-", $text);
        echo $cadenaConvert;
        }
     ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Amigo gracias, me lo has solucionado, wow...     :)